# Correlator $bc$ system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem

I have da doubt with bc system. Polchinski says (2.5.10)
$$
b(z)b(0)~=~O(z). \tag{2.5.10}
$$
I tried to compute the correlation function

1. With eom, using eq (2.5.6b) by Polchinki, removing the source $\delta\rightarrow 0$.
2. Using mode expansion and I get precisely 0.

Maybe I'm missing something. If it would not be zero, for instance, how to compute the OPE
$$
:b\partial^7b::bc:~?
$$